# In excel how to set a cost of 29.00 to a 11 digit no decimal point format

Tags: excel

How do I tell excel I want the first two digits to be assummed to be decimal places using NNNNNNNNNNN format? thx

I'm trying to use excel format to convert 29.00 to following:

```
00000002900
```

but it keeps look like the following:

```
00000000029  // how do I get the 29 to move up by two digits like the first one????
```

I'm using custom format in excel of "00000000000" but that is not working. thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, your custom format should be "00000000000" instead of "NNNNNNNNNNN" if I'm not mistaken.

If you don't want to see a decimal place you can store all your values in cents instead of dollars (multiply by 100) and use "00000000000". If you want to still use dollars and don't mind a decimal point use "000000000.00"

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can do that with a Format mask as the only way would be to actually modify the underlying value.

you could use; `=TEXT(A1*100,"00000000000")`